# For a classification problem, does a feature need to have a statistically significantly different mean within each class to be a predictive feature?

Tags: classification

I'm trying to improve my intuition surrounding machine learning algorithms.

Let's say I have a continuous feature (for example, let's use the length of a flower stem), and I'm considering using that feature in a classification model to help me predict the type of flower it is (let's restrict the problem to roses vs. violets).  Should the mean stem length for roses be statistically significantly different (through a Welch's t-test or some other test) from the mean stem length for violets if this feature is to be predictive in my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, one feature doen't need to have different mean value between classes. It can be the same, but the feature can help model with a decision in combination with other feature.

Let's have a look at the following example. `feature_2` has the same mean value for both classes. It doesn't have any predictive power itself. But in  the combination with `fetautre_1` model can find the decision better than just `feature_1`.

[image]